# Change HTTP PUT Request to HTTP PATCH Request using IAsyncActionFilter and rewrite the whole ActionDescriptor in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently converting from Asp.Net Framework to Core and working on finding a way to change an HTTP PUT/POST request to PATCH when the Content-Type = "application/json-patch+json". Changing the Method itself is NOT working. I think rewriting the whole ActionDescriptor will do the trick but I have no idea how to do it Below is the code I currently have.

```
public class FewzionActionSelector : IAsyncActionFilter {
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) {
        // Execute the rest of the MVC filter pipeline
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType != null && context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Equals("application/json-patch+json"))
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Put.Method) || context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Post.Method))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Request.Method = $"{HttpMethod.Patch.Method}";
                if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
                {
                    var actionAttributes = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);

                }
            }
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Action filters can change arguments, but the endpoint has already been selected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0 You'll need to run your code before the routing middleware (see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already [`UseHttpMethodOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.httpmethodoverrideextensions.usehttpmethodoverride?view=aspnetcore-6.0) baked into ASP.NET Core, and though it doesn't quite work exactly how you want it to, you could use the corresponding middleware's [code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware.cs) as a basis for your own middleware.

Alternatively, you could write it as an anonymous method in your startup's `Configure` method:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (string.Equals(context.Request.ContentType, "application/json-patch+json") 
        && (context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Post) || context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Put)))
    {
        context.Request.Method = HttpMethod.Patch.Method;
    }
    await next();
});
```

Whichever route you take, the middleware should be registered before your call to `app.UseRouting();`